# log4j 2 log.info() not giving the expected output

Tags: java, log4j

Friends, here is my code snippet. Couldn't be simpler.

```
 import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
 import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;



 public class Log4JTest {

 private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger("Log4JTest");
 public static void main(String args[])
 {

 log.info("Info Message!");

 }

 }
```

I've added the jar files in the classpath. The code compiles fine but I see nothing in the
console. Am I missing something??

Comment: post your log4J properties.

Comment: Which appender are you using?

Comment: If I just want to see just the message in the console, still do I have to configure log4j.properties. I believe only if you want to get the logs in the file we use appender. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ user2472968: console is another _Appender_